# React remove component from list

Tags: reactjs

Pretty new to React, coming from knockout

Below is a simplified example of my problem
I have a situation with a list of items, where I need to remove an item based on its expiration date

items below is an array of objects

Each object contains a name and an expiration date

```
class List extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: prop.items
        }
    }

componentDidMount(){
    window.setInterval(function(){


    }.bind(this), 5000);
}

    render() {
        return <div>
                {this.state.items.map(function(item, index){
                    return <ListItem key={index} {...item} />
                }.bind(this))}
        </div>
    }
}

class ListItem extends Component{
    expired(){
       return new Date() > new Date(this.props.expiration)
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <span>Name {this.props.name}</span>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I was thinking of running an interval and checking whether the ListItem has expired.
Ideally I would like to call the expired function on each of the ListItems from the List component

I have read about refs but it just seems a hack.

Is there no other way for the List component to have a list of the actual instances, so that it can invoke any method on the children?

Regards

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question...so I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for...but you can pass a function as a prop to List and then pass that prop to ListItem and invoke it from there

Answer (score 2):

In ReactJS, you can run JS essentially wherever you'd like, including the `render()` method. So why not just check the `expiration` prop before rendering the desired content? Now each time your `List` renders, each `ListItem` will also re-render() and run the check:

**ListItem.jsx**

```
render() {

    const { expiration, name} = this.props;

    if (expired(expiration)) {
        return <span />
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>Name: {name}</span>
        </div>
    )

}

expired(date) {
    return new Date() > new Date(date)
}
```

Comment: Hi. The thing is that they might not have expired at the time render() is called. So I was thinking of having an interval run every x seconds and check if any expired and remove them. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, that seems reasonable to a degree - and this solution still applies. By calling `this.forceUpdate()` in your `setInterval` in `List` you therefore force a render of all its children - as a result, `render()` will be called for each item in the list when the interval fires.

Comment: although it might work, it feels wrong. coming from knockout this would be straightforward. is there no way for a parent to access its children's instances?

Comment: @Thomas Parents can look into children via `refs`, or you provide a callback from the parent to the child. But why do you want the `List` to manage its children, when `ListItem` is already smart enough to manage itself? `ListItem` already knows whether it should display itself since you _explicitly_ passed it the expiration date. If the child _should not_ be making that decision, then just perform the check in `List` before you potentially render the `ListItem`, and don't pass down `expiration`.

Comment: Thanks Lux. i need to get in terms with the react way. appreciate your help